# Employee is not a known Entity type, though annotated as such

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I'm trying to configure a simple JPA project with EclipseLink and Payara.
I created a datasource in Payara and could ping it successfully. But when trying to persist my entity, I get:

```
Object: Employee(eid=1201, ename=Gopal, salary=40000.0, deg=Technical Manager) is not a known Entity type.
```

App:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "my_persistence_unit")
protected EntityManager em;

public void func() {

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEid(1201);
    employee.setEname("Gopal");
    employee.setSalary(40000);
    employee.setDeg("Technical Manager");

    em.persist(employee);
    em.flush();
    em.close();
}
```

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long eid;
   private String ename;
   private double salary;
   private String deg;

}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="my_persistence_unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myRes</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

POM:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakartaee}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Why `Employee` isn't a known entity, though I annotated it as `@Entity`?

Comment: The pom.xml configuration suggests that you are bundling your own version of EclipseLink with your application. Payara is a full JEE application server and bundles its own JPA implementation (it's probably EclipseLink, but that isn't important to you). Are you sure you want your _own_ implementation - this is probably interfering with the automatic entity discovery. If not, try marking the EclipseLink AND JPA jars as `<scope>provided</scope>`. If you need your own version, first try specifying your entity classes explicitly in persistence.xml.

Comment: Look at the logs during deployment (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging ) but as in the comment above, I would suspect packaging is preventing it from being found - class loaders provided to EclipseLink might not have the class accessible. Try listing your entity in the persistence.xml to ensure it is found, as the logs might also show errors/warning if it isn't that help point to the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove the dependencies on eclipselink and the persistence api from the pom.

If that doesn't help, try adding the Employee class to your persistence.xml:

your.package.Employee

Normally, this only needs to be done if the entity class is living in another module. If not, the automatic detection should work.